# How do I get the git revision of my project assuming there are no committed changes?

Tags: java, git, gradle

I want a way to be able to return "unknown" as my git revision if I have uncommitted changes locally. If not, it should return the correct git revision.

```
String getGitRevision() {
    String gitRevision = "unknown"
    try {
        def cmd = "git rev-parse HEAD"
        def proc = cmd.execute()
        gitRevision = proc.text.trim()
    }
    catch (IOException ioe) {
        println "Fetch revision failed."
    }
    return gitRevision;
}
```

I expect that when I have uncommitted changes locally, getGitRevision() returns unknown.

But even when I have uncommitted changes, it grabs the correct revision id. I'm not really sure how to add that logic in.

Answer (score 1):

`HEAD` is parseable as a commit as long as there is a current commit, and there is almost always a current commit.  "Uncommitted changes" is not relevant to whether there is a current commit.

To compare the index and work-tree *to* the current commit, use `git status`.  To do this reliably, in your own software, consider using `git --no-optional-locks status --porcelain=v2`, perhaps with `-z` as well, and reading its output, which is shown in [the `git status` documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-status#_porcelain_format_version_2).  Your code can then choose what to consider "uncommitted changes" (including untracked files, and, if you add `--ignored`, ignored files).

For this particular case, you can just use `git describe --always --dirty` and check for the `-dirty` suffix.  Or—since this is what `git describe` itself does—run `git diff-index --quiet HEAD` and check its exit status: 0 means "not dirty", 1 means "dirty", anything else means "unable to tell, something went wrong".  The method using `git status --porcelain...` is the most flexible, as it lets *you* define what *you* mean by "dirty", but the other two are much simpler.